# How to remove "<?xml ...>" tag from response?

Tags: java, html, regex, xml, string

I want to remove the following line from  my response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

I have used this regular expression:

```java
String newString = text.replaceAll("(?s)<xml>","");
```

But it doesn't work for me, what should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways. If you are pretty sure the XML is pretty-formatted (one line, one element) and this tag always appears on the first line, simply remove the whole line.

Since this requires a well-formatted XML, you'd better go for the Regex based solution that you suggest.

Try to use the `(<\?xml.*?\?>)` regex. See demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CbEt55/6). In Java, mind the escaped characters:

```
String newString = text.replaceAll("(<\\?xml.*?\\?>)","");
```

Comment: A well formed XML document doesn't have to include line breaks. E.g. `<?xml  version="1.0"?><data><?my_PI exec="command"?><child>One</child><child>Two</child></data>
` is a valid XML document that includes a [Processing Instruction](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/pi/). This regex will mess that up big time ;) [See your updated regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/CbEt55/5).

Comment: @ClasG: A very good hint, thank you for the comment. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you can get XML from first tag without question mark after it,as `<[^\?]+` see [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/14).

This will ignore `<?xml>` tag